# Starting with the last character and iterating backwards by 3

Tags: java, string, reverse, charat

I am trying to create a code that takes any string and relays it back to me backwards missing every 3rd character and including the very last character.

> EX: "123456789" should return "963" &
>   "Hello, World!" should return "!r lH"

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cypher {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String str = scnr.nextLine(); 
      String reverse = "";
      System.out.println(str.length());
      for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i - 3);
      }
      System.out.println(reverse);
   }
}
```

The code above is what I have so far. However when I run this code I get this error message: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1"

I don't understand because the string length is 10 so why is it not able to do this? Could someone explain this to me and give me a suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest just iterating the characters in the string, starting from the last position, and moving backwards in increments of 3:

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = scnr.nextLine();
String reverse = "";

for (int i=str.length()-1; i >= 0; i=i-3) {
    reverse += str.charAt(i);
}

System.out.println(reverse);
```

Your current approach is failing because the loop just takes single, not triple steps.  Also note that you might want to use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` to build the `reverse` string.  This might be more efficient (though the JVM itself might substitute `StringBuilder` on its own).

Answer (score 0):

According to your current logic `str.charAt(i - 3)` here when value of `i` becomes less than 3, your code will try to access and index that is a -ve number and thus throws this exception.

You'll have to check if `i - 3 >= 0` before using `str.charAt(i - 3)` else break out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You current logic is `str.charAt(i - 3)` and continue while `i >= 0`. The `str.charAt(i - 3)` statement will generate `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` when `i` is less than 3, thus you should change your code to this.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = scnr.nextLine();
    String reverse = "";
    System.out.println(str.length());
    for (int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i = i - 3) {
        reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
    }
    System.out.println(reverse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code in my system and it works fine. Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cypher {


public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  String str = scnr.nextLine(); 
  String reverse = "";
  System.out.println(str.length());
  for (int i = str.length() - 1; i>= 0; i-=3) {
    reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
  }
  System.out.println(reverse);


}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changed your code a little and this works fine now.

You were getting the `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` because your for loop decremented by a single step every time instead of the required step of 3. As a result when the string has less than 3 characters left the value of variable `i` becomes negative and an exception is thrown when the `charAt(i)` function is called with a negative value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class cypher {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      String str = scnr.nextLine(); 
      String reverse = "";
      System.out.println(str.length());
      int i = str.length() - 1;
      while(i >= 0)
      {
        reverse = reverse + str.charAt(i);
        i-=3;
      }
      System.out.println(reverse);
   }
}
```